# TFTP Server atftpd fails to start

Tags: 12.04, tftp

I have installed atftpd on Ubuntu 12.04, but it looks like I cannot start the tftp server, and there's a problem also with the tftpd daemon.
With Ubuntu 11.10 there was no problem.

```
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
atftpd (0.7.dfsg-11) wird eingerichtet ...
unknown protocol: udp4
```

With rlinetd, and also as daemon, it doesn't work.
with `ps -afe` I see no process.

`/var/log/syslog` says it cannot bind to ip address.

with option `--bind-adress`  the atftpd server starts but also doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

I've checked out atftpd source code, and find out that working line for `/etc/default/atftpd` is

```
USE_INETD=false
OPTIONS="--tftpd-timeout 300 --retry-timeout 5 --port=69 --maxthread 100 --verbose=5 /srv/tftp"
```

You need to specify port to fool atftpd. So now tftp server is available from all  network interfaces.

Comment: This was my problem, I realised I needed to change the `true` to `false` but it was the OPTIONS line that caught me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You are probably affected by bug [#993101](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/atftp/+bug/993101)

Please confirm if you are having same problem!
Eventually, you can always download the [source](http://packages.debian.org/source/squeeze/atftp) and install by yourself..

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got **atftpd** working in 12.04:

1. Edit `/etc/default/atftpd`

   a. Change `inetd=true` to `inetd=false`

   b. Removed all multicast options, added `--bind-address=<my local static ip>`

   c. Created `/tftpboot` directory (modify `/etc/default/atftpd` accordingly as the default directory is something else) with user `nobody` group `nogroup`

   d. Also added `--logfile /var/log/atftpd.log` (first `touch /var/log/atftpd.log` and set permissions accordingly)

   e. Set `--verbose=7` to capture all messages
2. Edit `/etc/rlinetd.conf` and made services available only local network by specifying my interface as my local IP address.
3. Stopped started `rlinetd`
4. Ran `invoke-rc.d atftpd start` as root.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: what is the point of step 2?

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu 12.04 LTS**

This system has an ip address of 192.168.0.5

> sudo touch /var/log/atftpd.log
>
> sudo chmod 644 /var/log/atftpd.log

here's my /etc/default/atftpd

```
USE_INETD=false
OPTIONS="--port=69 --tftpd-timeout 300 --retry-timeout 5 --mcast-port 1758 --mca
st-addr 192.168.0.0-255 --mcast-ttl 1 --maxthread 100 --verbose=7 /tftpboot --lo
gfile /var/log/atftpd.log"
```

> sudo mkdir /tftpboot
>
> sudo chmod 777 /tftpboot
>
> touch /tftpboot/simple.txt
>
> sudo invoke-rc.d atftpd restart

From another system (on the same subnet) running busybox

> tftp -l simple.txt -g 192.168.0.5